# Inclusion of generated subring, subfield

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A \subseteq B$ be rings. We define $A[b_1,\dots,b_n]$ as the subring of $B$ given by the evaluation of finite polynomials with coefficients in $A$ over $b_1,\dots,b_n$ (e.g. $\Bbb Z[i]$).

If $A$ and $B$ are fields, we define $A(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ as the smallest subfield of $B$ containing $b_1,\dots,b_n$ and A.

My course says that $A[b_1,\dots,b_n] \subseteq A(b_1,\dots,b_n)$. I think it should be $ A(b_1,\dots,b_n) \subseteq A[b_1,\dots,b_n]$, right ?

I could figure out that $\Bbb Q[i]$ was a field containing $Q$ and $i$ so maybe in this particular case the reverse inequality also holds but I found it legit to ask myself if the inequality in my course was wrong.

Comment: Obviously $A[b_1,\dots,b_n] \subset A(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ and $A[b_1,\dots,b_n] =A(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ holds only when the $b_j$ are algebraic over $A$

Comment: @reuns Then can you give me a link or quick proof for the inclusion $A[b_1, \dots , b_n] \subset A(b_1 , \dots , b_n)$ ? 
Thanks !

Comment: $A[b_1,\dots,b_n]$ is the smallest subring of $ B$ containing $A$ and the $b_j$

Comment: Every field is a ring, but not every ring is a field. Now think it through.